# How can i do this query faster? (postgreSQL)

Tags: sql, postgresql

Target - Day_1 Rolling retention in %

Questions:

1) how can i speed up this query?

2) this conversation to numeric is slow down query?

3) do i have any other options to round() it somehow else? or it's optimal?

**Query:**

```
SELECT date(reg_time), round(CAST(count(DISTINCT du.uid) / count(DISTINCT users.uid)::float * 100 AS numeric), 2) AS rolling_retention_day1
FROM users 
LEFT JOIN dailyusers du 
ON users.uid = du.uid
AND date(reg_time) BETWEEN current_date - interval '30' DAY AND current_date 
AND date(reg_time) + 1 <= day
GROUP BY date(reg_time);
```

Comment: Please edit your question and show the layout of the tables with their types.  Sample data and desired results would also help.  And why are there two conditions on `reg_time`?  What is `day`?  The conversion to numeric probably has a negligible affect on performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the right indexes, I suspect this will be faster:

```
SELECT reg_date, AVG(du_flag) as rolling_retention_day1
FROM (SELECT date(u.reg_time) as reg_date,
             (CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                                FROM dailyusers du
                                WHERE du.uid = u.uid AND
                                      date(u.reg_time) + 1 <= du.day
                               )
                   THEN 1 ELSE 0
              END) as du_flag
      FROM users u
      WHERE u.reg_time >= current_date - interval '30' day AND
            u.reg_time < current_date + interval '1' day
     )
GROUP BY reg_date;
```

You want indexes on `users(reg_time)` and `dailyusers(uid, day)`.  This assumes that `uid` is unique in `users`, which makes sense to me.

If you really care about the format of the average, then you can do:

```
AVG(du_flag)::decimal(4, 2)
```

This is the best I can do with the query you have given.  There may be a better way to write the query.  I would suggest you ask *another* question with sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what the query is doing (or supposed to be doing), if you want help with that.

Comment: reg_time is timestamp.

how much faster this solution? 

thx.)

Comment: @Andso . . . You have to try it to determine which is faster.

Answer (score 0):

`reg_time` is enclosed with  date function.

if `reg_time` is an indexed column, enclosing reg_time with date function breaks indexed search. You need to consider not to use `date(reg_time)`

you can also identify your query issues by using `SQL Explain Plan`